# How to load the saved pictures and save the pictures in SQLite database using eclipse?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wanted to save the pictures in my database and  load the picture through the database.How can i do that in eclipse?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where's your code?

Comment: I am unaware about the saving pictures to database and importing it from there. i just have the codes for importing the texts from database.

Comment: And why do you think that SO is a better search engine than Google?

Comment: Because i found that SO features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming, and i'm eager to learn the computer programming, hoping to get help and support from you i have joined it.

Answer (score 1):

you can store in database image base64 string and you can retrieve it also from database.